# UITableView scrolling up after cell selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have applied longPress gesture over my tableview cell for selection (because of such requirement). After I longpress any cell and it get selected a view from bottom appears and the tableview automatically scrolls upwards.
Also when I deselect the selected cell again the tableview scrolls to upwards.
Any help much appreciated.

```
func resetSelectedRequests()
{
    if arrSelectedIndex.count > 0 {
        if arrSelectedIndex.count == filteredRequests?.count {
            self.arrSelectedIndex.removeAll()
            self.isAllChecked = true
        }else {
            self.isAllChecked = false
        }

        if self.actionsViewHeightConstraint.constant == Height.height0.rawValue {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + TimeDelay.decimalTwentyFive.rawValue) {
                if arrSelectedIndex.count > 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeDelay.decimalOne.rawValue, delay: TimeDelay.zero.rawValue, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                        self.actionsViewHeightConstraint.constant = Height.height60.rawValue
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }

        }

        tblViewApproveRequest.reloadData()
        tblViewApproveRequest.layoutIfNeeded()

    }else {
        deselectAllRequests()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add LongPressGesture code.

Comment: @Kuldeep Please find the code in edited version of question.

Comment: what this `actionsViewHeightConstraint` does?

Comment: @ReinierMelian its just a view which is to be shown after cell gets selected and has some buttons for users to act upon.

Comment: but your tableView frame is affected by the constraint change of that view?

Comment: thats why i have used these lines: `tblViewApproveRequest.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: you need to save the current contentOffset before change and scroll the table view to the same point after the reloadData or do the reloadData without animation, try putting your reloadData and layoutIfNeeded inside this block    `UIView.performWithoutAnimation {(your code here)}` try this before to go deeper

Comment: Let me know if solves your issue

Comment: Is it necessary to reload the whole `tableView`?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Tried but no success!!!

Comment: can you share a video or something to see the wrong behavior?

Comment: @iPeter yes as i have some buttons on my cell whose layout is to be changed on selection/deselection of cell

Comment: Why don't you reload the cell only, reloading the tableView changes it contentOffset but reloading a particular cell does not. Please give it a try.

Comment: Let me make it more explanatory. As per my need when i long press on a cell, that cell gets selected and all other cells then get enabled for didSelect Delegate calling and also after long pressing a cell i need to show checkboxes on all other cells for getting them selected on either didSelect or long press both.
Hope this makes my problem more clearer now. :(